# Make Fancy Box Transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am calling a form in [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) i would like to make it transparent when the user clicks on it. I would like to make it transparent enough to see the background picture. I have managed to get the form in the iframe transparent however i am not sure how to get the fancybox itself transparent.

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/vwfTV/1/) of what i have thus far.

**Code**

**JS**

```
$("#open").click(function () {

    $.fancybox.open({
        content: '<iframe id="myFrame" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="about:blank" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>',
        autoSize: false,
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        scrolling: 'no',
        afterShow: function () {
            var oIframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
            var iframeDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow.document || oIframe.contentDocument);
            iframeDoc.open();
            iframeDoc.write(myContent);
            iframeDoc.close();

        }
    });
});

var myContent = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><title></title><style type=\"text/css\">html{height:100%;}body{height:100%;margin:0px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial;}label{float left;display:block;font-size:13px;padding:5px;clear:both;}input[type=text], input[type=password],select{flot: righ;width:250px;border: 1px solid #3F0B1B;}input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, select{background: #DDD;}ol {list-style-type: none;margin:0px;padding-left:15px;}ol ul{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-indent: -1em; margin-left: 1em;}.div{border: 1px solid black;}.fancybox{ overflow: hidden !important;}</style></head><body><div><ol> <li><label>Name</label><input type="text" id="name"/></li> <li><label>Phone #</label><input type="text" id="phone"/></li> <li><label>Address Line 1</label><input type="text" id="add1"/></li> <li><label>Address Line 2</label><input type="text" id="add2"/></li> <li><label>Address Line 3</label><input type="text" id="add3"/></li> <li><label>Email Add</label><input type="text" id="email"/></li> <li><label>Age</label><input type="text" id="age"/></li> <li><label>Date Of Birth</label><input type="text" id="dob"/></li> <li><input type="submit" value="Continue"/></li> </ol></div></body></html>';
```

**CSS**

```
body {background-image:url('http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg');} 

#myFrame{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  opacity:0.3;
  filter:alpha(opacity=30)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="open" href="javascript:;">Open me</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this in your CSS:

```
.fancybox-skin{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

That will change it so you can see through it.

The last `0.5` is what you want to change in terms of how opaque it is. The higher it is, the more opaque it is.

Comment: if i was calling another form via a link to be displayed in the fancybox where would i need to place this css code?

Comment: @devdar You can place it in the css file which is connected to the page where the fancybox will display.

Comment: `The last 0.5 is what you want to change in terms of how opaque it is. The higher it is, the less opaque it is.` ... is actually, the other way around.

Comment: @JFK You are correct! Good thing you read through this! I'll correct now thanks :)

Comment: Just use this: `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: I had to add !important also.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try with this:

```
.fancybox-skin {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

Check the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/vwfTV/3/**

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using this code

```
$.fancybox({
   helpers:{
     overlay : null
     }
});
```

I found it here: [official website](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Comment: No, this will only make the grey overlay disappears, instead of the iframe